# Ignore case sensitive in AWK Shell

Tags: shell

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/' '$1~/'$name'/' $file
```

It seems to have "runaway regular expression" error

How do i add in ignorecase for such cases?

```
 John:English:95:May
 May:Math:99:John
 Peter:Math:55:John
 May:Sci:76:John
```

my $file data

```
Please enter your name: may
```

User input

```
May:Math:99:Joh
May:Sci:76:John
```

Expected result

Comment: So sorry.. I am new..  But how do i accept the the answer?

Comment: Good that you have learnt to appreciate answers now! What is your problem here? Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Can you add an example of your requirement? Your input and an expected output?

Comment: sure, Thanks so much for the help. learnt something new today.. At first i thought up vote means accepted. Didnt notice there is a tiny tick below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `POSIX` compatible string functions `tolower()` and `topper()` for case-insensitive look-ups in `Awk` rather than using `GNU Awk` specific `IGNORECASE` which doesn't provide flexibility to change the case for specific needs but only as a whole.

Assuming your `$name` is read from user-input in a `bash` variable, you can do,

```
awk -F":" -v name="$name" 'tolower($1) ~ tolower(name)' file
May:Math:99:John
May:Sci:76:John
```

(or) if you intend to use `IGNORECASE`, do something like,

```
awk -F":" -v name="$name" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $1 ~ name' file
May:Math:99:John
May:Sci:76:John
```

This is assuming you are reading the user-input in a shell command using `read` and having the value stored in the variable `$name` in shell context.